# Voting on questions with multiple tags

Tags: discussion, down-votes

In the case of questions with multiple tags like [c](/questions/tagged/c) and [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), someone who is a C moderator cannot find value in it and votes it down but SQL people like the question and vote up, how is it resolved?

The problem comes when you view questions tagged [c](/questions/tagged/c), and it will have lots of down votes not done by C people.

Comment: what do tags have to do with the question's quality/content?

Comment: People vote as they like. So what?

Comment: Not sure where this is coming from, I can't see you posted any questions on other sites and you don't even have account on Stack Overflow.

Comment: People do not normally vote on questions because of their tags.

Comment: Have you seen this happen? Do you have a particular example? Given that you don't seem to have a Stack Overflow account, I wonder what exactly you base this argument on. An example might help.

Answer (score 2):

> ...someone who is c moderator cannot find value in it and vote it down...

I take that to mean that the question has little or noting to do with C programming, so the correct thing to do would be to remove the [c](/questions/tagged/c) tag. Anyone can suggest this, or other improvements, by editing the question.